# Trying to reduce/optimize if/else block to make more readable

Tags: java, if-statement

I have the following block of code. Basically it determines in baseball if a player gets a number of bases, what happens based on if someone is on 1st/2nd/3rd. I did this out brute force but is there a way to rewrite this to drastically reduce the line count? I haven't been able to come up with a good way to do it.

```
    int runsScored = 0;
    switch (action) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            if (third) {
                if (second) {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 2;
                        second = false;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 2;
                        first = true;
                        second = false;
                        third = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 1;
                        second = true;
                        third = false;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 1;
                        first = true;
                        third = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (second) {
                    if (first) {
                        third = true;
                    } else {
                        first = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (first) {
                        second = true;
                    } else {
                        first = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (third) {
                if (second) {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 2;
                        first = false;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 2;
                        third = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 1;
                        second = true;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 1;
                        second = true;
                        third = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (second) {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 1;
                        third = true;
                        second = true;
                        first = false;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (first) {
                        first = false;
                        second = true;
                        third = true;
                    } else {
                        second = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (third) {
                if (second) {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 3;
                        first = false;
                        second = false;
                        third = true;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 2;
                        second = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 2;
                        first = false;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 1;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (second) {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 2;
                        third = true;
                        second = false;
                        first = false;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 1;
                        second = false;
                        third = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 1;
                        first = false;
                        second = false;
                        third = true;
                    } else {
                        third = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (third) {
                if (second) {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 4;
                        first = false;
                        second = false;
                        third = false;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 3;
                        second = false;
                        third = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 3;
                        first = false;
                        third = false;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 2;
                        third = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (second) {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 3;
                        third = false;
                        second = false;
                        first = false;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 2;
                        second = false;
                        third = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (first) {
                        runsScored = 2;
                        first = false;
                        second = false;
                        third = false;
                    } else {
                        runsScored = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError();
    }
    return runsScored;
```

Comment: You should ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: Instead of all that, can't you come up with a formula that computes the same data?  Clearly it's a regular structure that could be reduced to a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd be describing this with class and letting it manage itself, but a good first step.

```
        if (third) {
            if (second) {
                if (first) {
                    runsScored = 2;
                    second = false;
                } else {
                    runsScored = 2;
                    first = true;
                    second = false;
                    third = false;
                }

        if (third) {
            if (second) {
                    runsScored = 2;
                    second = false;
                if (!first) {
                    first = true;
                    third = false;
                }
```

i.e. factor out the same code on either side of the else. Once you've cleared out some of the undergrowth, something simpler may become visible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with bitwise operators (shifts and bitwise and)

(see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

```
   int runsScored = 0;
   int action=1;
   boolean first = false;
   boolean second = true;
   boolean third = true;

   // Encode the bases in a bitstring.
   int onbases = 0;
   onbases += third ? 1 : 0;
   onbases <<= 1;
   onbases += second ? 1 : 0;
   onbases <<= 1;
   onbases += first ? 1 : 0;
   onbases <<= 1;

   // Bitmasks for use in the loop.
   int homeplate = 16;
   int basesloaded = 2+4+8;

   onbases += 1; // Represent the batter who hasn't yet left the plate.
   for (int i=0; i<action; i++) {
       onbases <<= 1;
       if ((onbases & homeplate) > 0) {
           runsScored += 1;
       }
   }
   // Remove the "players" who crossed home plate.
   onbases &= basesloaded;

   // onbases now reflects who's on base *after* the run.
   // Decode the bitstring.
   first = (onbases & 2) > 0;
   second = (onbases & 4) > 0;
   third = (onbases & 8) > 0;
```

`Integer.toBinaryString(int)` is useful for debugging, and if you use these operators, I find it helpful to go heavy on parentheses, because order-of-operations sometimes doesn't fall out intuitively.

**Edit**: What I posted earlier forgot to put the batter on base.  I believe it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `action` variable is what base the hitter will end up on, and `first, second, third` are booleans for batters on base:

Instead of checking each boolean, perhaps transform them into a single array. For example, a runner on first and third looks like `[1,0,1]`. A runner on second and third looks like `[0,1,1]`. Then you can write a function that takes in your `action` variable and the array of bases and returns the number of runs and the new bases array.

This could certainly remove the nested statements from your `case` statement, but maybe you can think of a way to make this work better than nested `if`s?

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version for the booleans (only):

```
boolean new_first = (action == 1) || (action == 2) && (first &!second & third);
boolean new_second = (action == 2) || (action == 1
                        && (first && !(second && third))
                        || (!first && second && !third));
boolean new_third = (action == 3)
        || (action == 2 && first)
        || (action == 1 && (first && second));
```

The `runsScored` part is harder.